# What the timeout for maven snapshots in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, jar, web, dependencies

I have web application that I run on tomcat embedded in eclipse.
It works ok, but when I try next day - it needs clean install/build/refresh all dependencies.
If I will not this - eclipse will not copy some dependencies. Each day I waste many time for this. Does exists way that possible work in Eclipse without do each day many rebuilds/refreshes, update dependencies/ project configuration etc.? Or at least - what snapshot timeout?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, but if you do not want your SNAPSHOT dependencies to be updated too frequently, you can configure this using `updatePolicy` parameter in `settings.xml` suitably.  For instance `never` will never update the snapshots.

From the [settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html),

> updatePolicy: This element specifies how often updates should attempt
>   to occur. Maven will compare the local POM's timestamp (stored in a
>   repository's maven-metadata file) to the remote. The choices are:
>   always, daily (default), interval:X (where X is an integer in minutes)
>   or never.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-snapshots</id>
      <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://url/to/my/snapshot/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```